# Conversions between CGAL::Extended_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> and CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

To convert from the object in the kernel `Simple_cartesian` to `Extended_cartesian` is simple. For example, I can do

```
CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>::Point_3 p_s(1, 2, 3);
CGAL::Extended_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>::Point_3 p_e(p_s.x(), p_s.y(), p_s.z());
```

My question is how to do it backwards? It seems that I cannot do it in the same way as above.
Assume I know that the number represented by the `Extended_cartesian` kernel number type is a finite rational number. After I check the FT type, it appears that the type is `CGAL::Nef_polynomial<CGAL::Gmpq>`. How can I properly convert it back to the standard type which is `CGAL::Gmpq` in this case? I would like to find a conversion that is lossless. In other words, converting it to `double` and then converting to `CGAL::Gmpq` is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended kernels are used only for **Nef polygons and polyhedra** to represent non-finite objects (like rays). In this case all the coordinates become *extended*, and this extension is achieved using the `CGAL::Nef_polynomial` type. It looks like objects of this type are represented by arrays of coefficients. If you work with regular points (which are called in CGAL *standard* points) only, then their coordinates will be represented by first elements of these arrays - so, the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Extended_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Gmpq.h>

using KernelE = CGAL::Extended_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>;
using PointE = KernelE::Point_3;

using KernelS = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>;
using PointS = KernelS::Point_3;

int main()
{
  PointE const pe{1, 2, 3};
  std::cout << pe << std::endl;
  PointS const ps(pe.x()[0], pe.y()[0], pe.z()[0]);
  std::cout << ps << std::endl;
}
```

The approach above might be not what CGAL developers planned. Actually I looked at the `Extended_cartesian.h` header and found a function `standard_point`, which returned what you wanted (but only for points in 2D):

```
Standard_point_2 standard_point(const Point_2& p) const
/*{\Xop returns the standard point represented by |p|.
\precond |\Mvar.is_standard(p)|.}*/
{ CGAL_assertion( type(p)==STANDARD );
  return Standard_point_2(p.x()[0],p.y()[0]);
}
```

So, the solution above is similar to this function.